# How to delete "weird" columns from pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

This code returns the name of the `dfESPCTC` column names

```
print list(dfESPCTC.columns.values)

[('DateTime', ''), (u'bid', 'close'), (u'bid', 'high'), (u'bid', 'low'), (u'bid', 'open')]
```

How do I drop everything but the close from the dataframe? I tried this but it doesn't work

```
dfESPCTC = dfESPCTC.drop('(bid, high)', 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DataFrame has a column [MultiIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html). To drop all but the `close` column, just select the one column:

```
dfESPCTC = dfESPCTC[[(u'bid', 'close')]]
```

If you index `dfESPCTC` using a list, then the result is a DataFrame.
If you pass just the column tuple (e.g. `dfESPCTC[(u'bid', 'close')]`), then the result is a Series.